# ASP.NET MVC3 - Clear cache from another application (subdomain)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have application on www.domain.com, and admin application on admin.domain.com.
Now, at some point I want to clear output cache on domain.com from admin.domain.com

Is that possible?

Comment: So far, I have two passoible solutions.
First is to have some flag in DB indicating that I want to clear cache, and chech for that on ActionExecuting (stinks too much).  
Second one is to call action method on domain.com.  
None of these seems good enugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonp did the trick in the end.